# Is there a way to check when mouse is above standard window control buttons (close, minimize etc)?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'd like to run a method when mouse is above one of the standard window controls (close, minimize, maximize). How do I do that?

[image: I'm talking about these]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use this:

```
internal const int WM_NCMOUSEMOVE = 0x00A0;

protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    if (m.Msg == WM_NCMOUSEMOVE)
    {
        if ((int)m.WParam == 0x8)
            Console.WriteLine("Mouse over on Minimize button");

        if ((int)m.WParam == 0x9)
            Console.WriteLine("Mouse over on Maximize button");

        if ((int)m.WParam == 0x14)
            Console.WriteLine("Mouse over on Close button");
    }

    base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

just put it in your form's code.

Comment: Right idea, but do favor WM_NCHITTEST.

Comment: Why and how? When using WM_NCHITTEST, WParam and LParam don't change it's value while moving mouse over these three buttons, so how can you know, which button are you hovering right now?

Comment: It is the m.Result value, after calling base.WndProc()

Answer (score 0):

Yes you could use a tooltip control the button when the MouseHover Event is triggered.

VB code...

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As
System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.MouseHover
ToolTip1.SetToolTip(Button1, "sometext")
End Sub
```

Here is some more info. Hope it helps.
http://bytes.com/topic/visual-basic-net/answers/683286-hover-text-command-buttons

Comment: hmmm, windows controls... I was thinking standard controls from the toolbox. Got me there...

Answer (score 0):

You can alternatively use this custom user control.Check whether this is apt for you.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42223/Easy-Customize-Title-Bar

Answer (score -2):

If you don't have too many controls, add an event handler to the mouse over event of the controls.