# Forms title bar buttons issues

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

[Is there a way to check when mouse is above standard window control buttons (close, minimize etc)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12329421/is-there-a-way-to-check-when-mouse-is-above-standard-window-control-buttons-clo)

This code is not mine. I went through the above link and I had made some alteration according for my requirement. I'm trying to code mouse enter & mouse leave event for minimize & close button of form in c#?

```
    SpeechSynthesizer reader;
    internal const int WM_NCMOUSEMOVE = 0x00A0;

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == WM_NCMOUSEMOVE)
        {
            //Mouse over on Minimize button
            if ((int)m.WParam == 0x8)
            {
                reader = new SpeechSynthesizer();
                reader.SpeakAsync("Minimize button");
            }

            //Mouse over on Maximize button
            if ((int)m.WParam == 0x9)
            {
                reader = new SpeechSynthesizer();
                reader.SpeakAsync("Maximize button");
            }

            //Mouse over on Close button
            if ((int)m.WParam == 0x14)
            {
                reader = new SpeechSynthesizer();
                reader.SpeakAsync("Close button");
            }
        }

        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
```

My Question:

1. How can I use *reader.SpeakAsync* (Asynchronous) method without repeating. Since if I use *reader.speak* (Synchronous) that will wait process until it finish reading text.
2. Also I need to implement mouse leave event. Because if mouse leaves the button, I do want to call *reader.Dispose()* method. Are there any way to implement mouse leave events?

Please help.

Comment: 1: use a variable that keeps track.  2: don't create a SpeechSynthesizer over and over again.

Comment: If you want to cancel the current speech so you can replace it with something new then use SpeechSynthesizer.SpeakAsyncCancelAll().  If you want to not speak if the current speech isn't done, then toggle a flag and then toggle it back in the SpeechSynthesizer.SpeakCompleted() event.  Check the flag so you don't attempt to speak over something already being said.

Comment: @Idle_Mind thanks better solution :)

Answer (score 3):

Your `WndProc` should merely translate Win32 messages and dispatch them to your program's logic. For example:

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    if (m.Msg == WM_NCMOUSEMOVE)
    {
        //Mouse over on Minimize button
        if ((int)m.WParam == 0x8)
        {
            Speak("Minimize button");
        }
        else if ((int)m.WParam == 0x9)
        {
            Speak("Maximize button");
        }
        else ...

    }

    ...
}

private SpeechSynthesizer _reader;

void Speak(string toSpeak)
{
    if (_reader == null)
    {
        _reader = new SpeechSynthesizer();
    }

    _reader.SpeakAsync(toSpeak);
}
```

I don't know the API of this class, so I don't know if I'm using it properly, [check the manual yourself](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.synthesis.speechsynthesizer.aspx). You can dispose the `_reader` when your form is being disposed.

You can also replace the strings with variables, constants, enums, resources or whatever you like, you can swap the `if`'s for a `switch`, in other words: this isn't copy & paste code, but I hope you catch the general idea.

Just curious, what are you building? Isn't this functionality already present in the OS? It would be a shame if every program would have to implement accessibility by itself.

Comment: I am building a system for blind people. Well this code repeatedly speaking once the mouse over occur. If I changed reader.speak that will one time speak but because of this synchronous method(reader.speak) that will lock other task. So the reason why I am expecting disposing method. :(